# Does the standard deviation of a normal distribution change when looking at a shorter period?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, expectation, standard-deviation

Say we are given a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, where $\mu$ is the expectation in time period $T$.

Now, say you need to use the distribution over a shorter time period, say $t, t < T$.

It stands to reason that the expectation over this time period $t$ is $\frac{t}{T}\mu$. However, what can be said about the standard deviation in this period? Will it remain $\sigma$?

Comment: What does it mean to "consider the distribution over a shorter period"? To consider the conditional distribution given by the constraint $t<T$?

Comment: I mean that we are given a distribution which describes a demand over a time period T, and we are asked to say something about the demand over  a time period t.

For example, in this case, we are told the expected demand over a week is normally distributed with mean $\mu$ and std.dev. $\sigma$, but I need to work with the expected demand over a number of days instead of a week.

Comment: No, it won't stay constant. Variance is proportional to $t$, so $\sigma(t)=\sigma(T){\sqrt\frac t T} $